# All symbols after "&" stripped

Tags: php, sql, mysql

My query:

```
mysql::getInstance()->update('requests', array('response' => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status'])), array('secret' => $_POST['secret'])); ?>
```

If i wand to add string with "&" symbol, all symbols after "&" stripped.

Example:
 string: **!"№;%:?*()_+!@#$%^&*()_+**

in database i see only: **!"№;%:?*()_+!@#$%^**

How to fix this?

update function, if anyone need:

```
function update($table, $updateList, $whereConditions)
{
    $updateQuery = '';
    foreach ($updateList as $key => $newValue) {
        if (!is_numeric($newValue)) {
            $newValue = "'" . $newValue . "'";
        }
        if (strlen($updateQuery) == 0) {
            $updateQuery .= '`' . $key . '` = ' .  $newValue;
        } else {
            $updateQuery .= ', `' . $key . '` = ' .  $newValue;
        }
    }
    return $this->query('UPDATE ' . $table . ' SET ' . $updateQuery . $this->buildWhereClause($whereConditions));
}
```

UPD:
echo mysql::getInstance()->getLastSQL() says:

```
UPDATE requests SET `response` = '!\"№;%:?*()_ !@#$%^' WHERE `secret` = '52a4ab5f7f3e8491e60b71db7d775ee2'
```

so, problem with function update in mysql class?

**Slaks**, i need to use str_replace('&', '%28', $query); ?

Comment: If you echo `$_POST['status']`, what do you see?

Comment: As a sidenote: Your update routine should ensure escaping the newValue strings, not the caller.

Comment: hurikhan77, please, can i look example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably passing a raw `&` character in the querystring, which causes everything after the `&` to be parsed as second parameter by PHP.  (Before it gets into your variable)

You need to escape the `&` as `%26`.

**EDIT**: You need to escape it before you send it to the server.  (When you make the HTTP request)